# Revisión Publicaciones de Baja Calidad

Tags: soporte, colas-de-revisión

Cuando me pongo a revisar las Publicaciones de Baja Calidad me encuentro a un dilema. No siempre aparecen las mismas opciones y debido a que ninguna de las que me muestra la plataforma es la que creo adecuada he de darle a omitir.

Por ejemplo, recomendar el cierre por "Baja calidad". A veces las respuestas/preguntas simplemente son de baja calidad, ni amplias ni preguntan muchas cosas, pero no me deja reportarlo como tal. En otras ocasiones si esta.

No se si sera por que ya ha sido reportada como tal, pero en caso de que esto suceda, ¿cómo he de actuar?

[Ejemplo de pregunta revisada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/161041/como-puedo-fijar-un-zoom-m%C3%A1ximo-en-webview)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Era una de muy baja calidad. Se entiende lo que pone el usuario, pero sin aportación de código. Por lo tanto, no es ni demasiado amplia, pero si está claro lo que pregunta (claro, si entiendes de que habla). No se basa en opiniones y si esta relacionado con SO. Tampoco es un duplicado.

Comment: Yo la consideraría como "no está claro lo que se pregunta" (o incluso como "demasiado amplia", la línea entre ambas es algo borrosa a veces). El ejemplo, aunque parezca un problema concreto, realmente no lo es tanto. Sin la investigación previa o los intentos/errores que haya obtenido, la pregunta se abre muchas posibilidades. Como un ejemplo algo extremo, es como si yo pregunto "¿cómo me conecto a MySQL desde PHP?" sin poner nada de lo que haya intentado o los requisitos de mi sistema, es un problema concreto (conectarse a MySQL) pero tiene muchas formas de resolverse.

Comment: A mi me pasa también mucho eso y algunas las pongo como **no esta claro lo que se pregunta** o **demasiado amplia**, muchas veces doy también a omitir porque no me gusta poner razones que creo que no se ajustan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Por ejemplo, recomendar el cierre por "Baja calidad". A veces las respuestas/preguntas simplemente son de baja calidad, ni amplias ni preguntan muchas cosas, pero no me deja reportarlo como tal. En otras ocasiones si esta.

El reporte de muy baja calidad (VLQ) sólo está disponible los primeros siete días luego de que se publicó y sólo en publicaciones con una puntuación de cero o menos.

Existen privilegios que permiten a los usuarios acceder a una cola especial de revisión de las preguntas VLQ, votar para eliminar o bien eliminar directamente.

En general, si no ves la opción de votar VLQ, lo más sencillo es votar como **no está claro lo que se pregunta**.

Referencias

- [Unable to flag as 'very-low-quality' (for answers)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326585/1595451)
- [¿Cómo debo de usar el reporte [muy baja calidad] (en inglés VLQ)?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3464/65)

Comment: Gracias Ruben, entonces ante estos casos entiendo que debo de votar: "no está claro lo que se pregunta"

Comment: @GDP A mi queda muy claro cuando se trata de preguntas VLQ en las que no esté la opción de votar VLQ hay que seleccionar "no está claro lo que se pregunta". Hay algunos hilos de los que se habla de esto en Meta SE (en inglés) seguramente valdría la pena traducir algunas de las explicaciones para que cada uno forme su criterio con  base en fundamentos fuertes.