# ¿Cómo debo de usar el reporte [muy baja calidad] (en inglés VLQ)?

Tags: soporte, faq, reportes

Al hacer clic en reportar en ocasiones veo la opción **Muy baja calidad**.

- ¿Cuándo debe usar esta opción?
- No se muestra en todas las publicaciones. ¿Por qué?

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Comment: La idea de esta publicación es ser enlazada en el artículo de ayuda Reportar publicaciones, específicamente en el enlace *Guía de uso para muy baja calidad*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>Traducción de [la respuesta de Jeff Attwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606/289691) a [Is the Very Low Quality flag too ambiguous?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93595/289691) con alguna adición para actualizar su contenido.</sub>

Muy baja calidad (VLQ por sus siglas en inglés)  significa que quien reportar piensa que la publicación es *insalvable* -- no hay edición o corrección que vuelva este particular zurullo  en oro. Es un llamado para un recogedor de heces. Para aclarar esto, estamos haciendo el lenguaje un poco más fuerte:

> **muy baja calidad**
>
> Esta pregunta/respuesta tiene problemas severos de formato o contenido. Es improbable que esta pregunta/respuesta pueda ser salvada mediante edición y podría necesitar ser eliminada.

Esencialmente esto es sinónimo de **repotar para eliminar**. Tanto la publicación *e* implícitamente para el usuario que creó esa publicación … si acumulan suficientes de estos.

La presencia de la opción de reporte VLQ –observe que ahora sólo aceptamos reportes VLQ en publicaciones con una puntuación de **cero o menor** durante los **[primeros siete días](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326635)**– es exactamente como un letrero de "no tirar basura". Le dice a los denunciantes, y a cualquier otro que se preocupa por darse cuenta, que ese desperdicio tóxico (también conocido como contenido de muy baja calidad que no puede ser rescatado mediante ninguna cantidad sensata de edición) no está permitido en nuestra comunidad. Está justo allí, en el aviso en las opciones de reporte: nosotros no toleramos publicaciones, *o usuarios* , que consistentemente contaminan nuestro sistema tirando desperdicio aquí:

[image: No Dumping - $500 fine sign]

Mientras que un voto negativo significa "tal vez este usuario solo está teniendo un mal día", un reporte por baja calidad significa **esta publicación, y posiblemente este usuario, está apestando completamente el lugar y debe ser expulsado lo antes posible**.

(Observa que en casos que extremos, puedes votar negativo *y* reportar como de baja calidad para acelerar ese proceso)

Estamos haciendo dos cambios para mejorar el manejo de este reporte:

1. El reporte VLQ ahora tiene un voto negativo de la Comunidad. Es como un "reporte ligero de contenido no deseado", es decir, no hay penalidad de reputación, pero al igual que al spam, se aplica un voto negativo del usuario Comunidad. Eso sí, si después de que se marque el reporte como útil, la respuesta recibe un voto positivo, entonces ese voto negativo se retractará automáticamente.
2. Si la publicación es *editada", cualquier reporte VLQ pendiente es eliminado  (sin dañar) de la publicación. No está claro que una publicación siga siendo VLQ si ha sido editada después del reporte.