# ¿Qué enlaces de las páginas del Centro de Ayuda apuntan a artículos en inglés?

Tags: discusión, traducciones, centro-de-ayuda

Tal y como vimos en distintas respuestas a [Traduzcamos las páginas y enlaces del "Centro de Ayuda" y de "Privilegios"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3264/83), el Centro de Ayuda y las páginas de privilegios contienen enlaces a otros Stacks (especialmente a [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)) y a blogs.

Este castillo llamado Stack Exchange tiene cerca de diez años y durante este tiempo se ha ido generando mucho contenido, mucha gente ha aportado su granito de arena (o granazo) y el contenido del que disponemos para SOes es inmenso. A nuestro ritmo, a hombros de esos gigantes que nos precedieron, será interesante que poco a poco vayamos incorporando a la red las traducciones de estas publicaciones tan potentes y que se consideran canónicas, para que así sus referencias en el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) sean en nuestro idioma.

Por ello, emplazo a detallar qué enlaces de los artículos del Centro de Ayuda (y según como de la página de privilegios y otras de ayuda) están apuntando a páginas aún no traducidas. En base a ello, y siguiendo la idea de [¿Sabes inglés, quieres aportar a la comunidad de SOes y no sabes cómo? ¡Traduce un FAQ!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1380/83), iremos tachando estos elementos. Y algún día, esperamos que no muy lejano, la lista estará vacía y podremos marcar esta pregunta como *estado-completado*.

Así pues, **¿qué enlaces de las páginas del Centro de Ayuda apuntan a artículos en inglés?**

A medida que las traducciones vayan existiendo, edita la página para señalarlo (por ejemplo, tachando la versión inglesa y referenciando la que está en castellano *<s>inglés</s> -> castellano*). Luego puedes hacer una Pull Request en el repositorio de la documentación, tal y como se describe en [¿Cómo puedo sugerir correcciones ortográficas en la documentación oficial?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3553/83).

Answer (score 3):

## Páginas de [privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

#### [Reportar publicaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

- [Guía de uso para *spam* y *grosero/abusivo*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035) (respuesta a [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), se incluye en ...¡Traduce un FAQ!)
- [Guía de uso para *no es una respuesta*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81392) (respuesta a duplicado)
- [Guía de reporte *fuera de tema*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169824) (respuesta a discusión)
- [Guía de uso para *muy baja calidad*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606) (respuesta a característica nueva)

  - Traducción propuesta: [¿Cómo debo de usar el reporte [muy baja calidad] (en inglés VLQ)?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3464/65)
- [Guía para comentar reportes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365) (respuesta a [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), se incluye en ...¡Traduce un FAQ!)

Answer (score 2):

## Páginas del [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) → [Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

A continuación se listan todos aquellos artículos que tienen algún enlace a páginas en inglés.

#### [¿Por qué ya no se aceptan preguntas desde mi cuenta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)

- [realizar preguntas es un privilegio, no un derecho](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/04/asking-better-questions/), entada del blog de Jeff Atwood
- [Writing the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) por Jon Skeet
- <s>[How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), de Meta Stack Exchange</s> -> [¿Cómo doy formato al código en mis publicaciones?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4039/83)

#### [¿Por qué veo un mensaje mencionando que mi pregunta no cumple con los estándares de calidad?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error)

- [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

#### [¿Qué son las etiquetas, y cómo debo usarlas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

#### [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

- https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions
- https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asking-questions
- http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

#### [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

- Eric Lippert → https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

#### [¿Qué significa si una pregunta está "cerrada" o "en espera"?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

- [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work)

#### [¿Por qué algunas preguntas son marcadas como duplicadas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

#### [¿Por qué y cómo algunas preguntas son eliminadas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)

- [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

#### [Cómo formular preguntas en el Beta Privado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask-beta)

- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/
- https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/
- https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/22/are-some-questions-too-simple/
- discuss on meta debería estar en castellano

Answer (score 2):

## Páginas del [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) → [Nuestro modelo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange)

A continuación se listan todos aquellos artículos que tienen algún enlace a páginas en inglés.

#### [¿Cuál es la conducta esperada de los usuarios?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

- publicidades gratuitas: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/05/31/community-promotion-ads/

#### [El usuario "Comunidad" ha eliminado mi pregunta. ¿Qué pasó?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)

- Quién es Community: [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)

#### [¿Qué debería contener el extracto de etiqueta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts)

- wiki de etiqueta: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/

#### [¿Cómo realizo una búsqueda?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

- una respuesta aceptada o con votos positivos: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/
- qué son wiki de comunidad: [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

#### [No te conviertas en un spammer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

- Tu respuesta está en otro canal: ¿cuando es una respuesta no una respuesta?: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)
- anuncio de promoción comunitaria: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/

#### [¿Qué significa "beta"?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-beta)

- proceso abierto y democratico: http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq
- nombra moderadores: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/
- elección democrática: [There's an election going on. What's happening and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work)
- siete preguntas esenciales: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/
- durante el tiempo necesario para alcanzar la amasa crítica: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/21/when-will-my-site-graduate/

#### [¿Cómo darle formato a mis publicaciones utilizando Markdown o HTML?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

- markdown: https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/
- un poco de HTML: <s>[What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)</s> -> [¿Qué etiquetas HTML están permitidas en los sitios de Stack Exchange?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4113/83)
- visitar la página de referencia: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax
- será inferido a partir de las etiquetas de la pregunta: [Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting)
- uno de los códigos de lenguaje soportados: [Interface options for specifying language prettify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970)

#### [¿Qué es "meta" y cómo funciona?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

- meta-etiquetas: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Answer (score 1):

## Páginas del [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) → [Reputación y moderación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange)

A continuación se listan todos aquellos artículos que tienen algún enlace a páginas en inglés.

#### [¿Qué es la reputación? ¿Cómo se gana (y se pierde)?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

- bonus de asociación: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/

#### [¿Quiénes son los moderadores del sitio, y cuál es su cometido?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)

- moderadores pro tempore: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/
- acuerdo del moderador: https://es.stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement
- proteger preguntas: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/07/new-protected-question-status/
- suspensión temporal: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/
- una teoría de la moderación: <s>http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation</s> -> [Una teoría de moderación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2227/83)

#### [¿Qué es una publicación bloqueada?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts)

- sistema en sí: [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)
- rechazada: [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)
- guerra de ediciones: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/04/the-great-edit-wars/
- guía moderar comentarios: [A guide to moderating comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments)

#### [¿Qué es una recompensa? ¿Cómo puedo iniciar una?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

- de entre las mostradas: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/bounty-%20reasons-and-post-notices/