# El acuerdo de moderador no aparece en Transifex

Tags: característica-nueva, estado-rechazado, traducciones, agregar-a-transifex

Mirando [¿Qué enlaces de las páginas del Centro de Ayuda apuntan a artículos en inglés?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3469/83) vi que el acuerdo de moderador no está traducido: https://es.stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement

¿Podríais añadirlo a Transifex?

Pensé que era una página normal, pero [g3rv4 comentó](https://github.com/g3rv4/help-pages/issues/24) que debe ponerse en Transifex.

Comment: un pequeño tip: las páginas del centro de ayuda son las que se pueden encontrar usando el buscador [en la página principal de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: @g3rv4 ¿esto quiere decir todo lo que hay en [`/help`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help)?

Comment: suena a que si :) pero no sé si hay alguna cosa en el centro de ayuda en otra url... miré el código y lo que sí puedo decir es que: si aparece en el buscador => es un artículo de ayuda. **Esto está mal:** *También puedo decir que si aparece en /help => es un artículo de ayuda*. No puedo decir que si no está en `/help` => no es un artículo de ayuda :) también puedo decir que todos los artículos de ayuda aparecen en el buscador!... entonces, si no está en el buscador => no es un artículo de ayuda

Comment: espero que mi lógica tenga sentido... pero hoy es viernes

Comment: Mmm veo que [Medallas](/help/badges) (`/help/badges`) y parece que el buscador no la encuentra si en el buscador pongo _Además de ganar reputación con tus preguntas y respuestas_. Pero bueno, menudencias.

Comment: ah, bien... Medallas no es una página del centro de ayuda (la traducción de esa página se hace mediante Transifex)... así que "si aparece en `/help` => artículo de ayuda" es falso. La posta posta es el buscador. La cadena que mencionas [está en Transifex, y como tal se traduce en traducir.win](https://traducir.win/string/8790)

Comment: PR creado... ahora a esperar...

Comment: el PR fue rechazado porque en este momento se está trabajando en mover todos los documentos legales a un lugar distinto (y el acuerdo de moderadores es uno de esos documentos). Esto es por GDPR, así que esos cambios van a estar en producción antes del 25 de Mayo, así que antes de esa fecha no va a pasar nada con esto. Si sumamos que estoy de viaje entre el 19/5 y el 6/1, esto no se va a mover hasta Junio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nuestro CM [Nicolas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/10/nicolas-chabanovsky) comenta en The Terminal:

> Hi! It seems on international sites we will not get it translated. I talked to my coworkers about the issue a few years ago in a context of SOru. The answer was that it's a legal document but we do not have neither an entity nor a consultant who would tell us if the doc is okay for a particular country, as a recall the talk.
>
> <sub>[Nicolas Chabanovsky, 29 octubre 2018](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47392319#47392319)</sub>

Esto es, que no se va a traducir porque no tienen los consultores jurídicos para determinar cómo adaptarlo a cada país en concreto.