# ¿Cómo puedo sugerir correcciones ortográficas en la documentación oficial?

Tags: soporte, centro-de-ayuda, propuesta-de-faq

Me encontraba leyendo documentación oficial para participar de manera responsable, y me encontré con una pequeña falta ortográfica, que si bien no es muy importante, sí lo es el hecho de conocer si existe una o varias herramientas disponibles que nos permitan aportar de esta manera.

Si eres un usuario mas experimentado ¿ya tienes esta opción disponible? ¿Cual es la reputación a la que debo llegar para poder aportar de esta manera?.

El error en cuestión pertenece a [¿Qué es la reputación? ¿Cómo se gana (y se pierde)?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), cuyo frase inicial es incorrecta:

> **A medida que ganes más reputación ganes**, obtendrás más privilegios y podrás acceder a más herramientas del sitio. Cuando llegues al mayor nivel de privilegios tendrás acceso a muchas de las herramientas disponibles para los moderadores del sitio. Esto tiene una intención claro: nosotros no hacemos funcionar el sitio, ¡la comunidad es la que lo hace!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para sugerir mejoras en la documentación debes hacer una pull request en el [repositorio Help Pages de GitHub](https://github.com/g3rv4/help-pages).

Dicho lo cual, si quieres que la comunidad se involucre en el proceso puedes seguir estos pasos:

1. Mirar si está [en github](https://github.com/g3rv4/help-pages)

   1. a. Si no está, hacer un issue para que g3rv4 lo añada.
2. Hacer una pregunta en Meta para coordinar todos los cambios
3. Dejar pasar un tiempo para juntar feedback
4. Hacer un PR con los cambios de la versión final

Es algo más tedioso pero así tienes más "ojos" que vean el texto y así dejen un texto más pulido.

Comment: actualizado con lo [comentado por g3rv4 en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49576622#49576622).