# Discutir corrección de "para todas las preguntas sobre Stack Overflow en español" en el discurso de ascensor (elevator pitch) del recorrido ¿sí o no?

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, temática

## Resumen

Considero que en el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) hay que cambiar

> para todas las preguntas sobre Stack Overflow en español

por

> para todas las preguntas sobre programación, desarrollo y uso de software.

Pero es algo distinto a SO y SOpt. ¿Es necesario discutirlo antes de hacer el cambio?

## Explicación

Quienes seguimos el sitio desde que arrancó si no es que desde antes, sabemos que este sitio no es una simple "localización" de Stack Overflow, sino que manteniendo el modelo de operación de preguntas y respuestas somos nosotros quienes determinamos la temática y algunas otras cosas del sitio.

- [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/65)

Luego de encontrar una extensa discusión en [¿Hasta que punto el ser estrictos beneficia a la comunidad?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3594/65), se me ocurrió volver a visitar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y cuál sería mi sorpresa que dice "para todas las preguntas **sobre Stack Overflow en español**" lo cual podría ser apropiado para Meta pero ni Meta tiene un recorrido ni el sitio principal es para preguntas sobre sí mismo. No recuerdo si que en las ocasiones anteriores que lo visité dijera eso, pero no tampoco encuentre discusiones sobre el discurso de elevador (elevator pitch) del sitio.

Tal vez no es cosa de darle muchas vueltas y sea sólo hacerle la petición a Juan M. (no creo que esto sea tema de traducir.win ni de hacer un PR al repo de "help pages" de g3rv4).

¿Qué opinan? ¿Están de acuerdo en que se haga la petición de lo indicado en el resumen sin discutirlo?

### Actual

> **Stack Overflow en español** es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas para programadores y entusiastas del desarrollo y uso de software. Lo construyes y lo administras *tú* como parte de la red de sitios de preguntas y respuestas de [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/). Con tu ayuda, trabajamos juntos para crear una biblioteca de respuestas detalladas para todas las preguntas sobre Stack Overflow en español.

### Actual del sitio en inglés

> **Stack Overflow** is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run *by you* as part of the [Stack Exchange network](http://stackexchange.com/) of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.

### Actual del sitio en portugués

> **Stack Overflow em Português** é um site de perguntas e respostas para programadores profissionais e entusiastas. É construído e administrado *por você* como parte da rede [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/) de sites de perguntas e respostas. Com a sua ajuda, trabalhamos em conjunto para desenvolver uma biblioteca de respostas detalhadas para cada pergunta sobre programação.

## Relacionado

- [¿Cómo puedo sugerir correcciones ortográficas en la documentación oficial?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3553/65)

Comment: +1 totalmente de acuerdo Ruben

Comment: El primer punto definitivamente debería de cambiar, apoyo la propuesta de Rubén.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se ha editado [la descripción](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y ahora refleja con mayor claridad lo que somos y lo que tratamos gracias a la sugerencia que se hizo aquí. Véase la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]