# Enlace incorrecto en el centro de ayuda para la sección Reputación y Moderación

Tags: soporte, centro-de-ayuda

Estaba revisando (leyendo) en el centro de ayuda sobre: [¿Qué es una recompensa?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

Al llegar la interrogante de ***¿Cómo inicio una recompensa?*** Que dice:

> Se puede iniciar una recompensa en una pregunta dos días después de ser publicada. Para iniciar una recompensa, haz clic en el enlace “iniciar una recompensa” situado en la parte inferior de la pregunta y reserva entre 50 y 500 puntos de reputación, en incrementos de 50. También puedes elegir una razón ***de entre las mostradas en una lista*** para ayudar a otros usuarios a entender por qué no estás satisfecho con ninguna de las respuestas existentes. Si necesitas explicar algo con más detalle, opcionalmente también puedes incluir un texto explicativo que se mostrará junto con la razón del ofrecimiento de la recompensa.

Al darle click al enlace ***de entre las mostradas en una lista*** me percate que apunta a una dirección errónea.

La misma apunta a:

`https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/09/bounty-%20reasons-and-post-notices/`

Y debería ser:

`https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/09/23/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/`

Comment: ¡Oh!, no sabía sobre [sugerir mejoras en la documentación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3556/107347), mi publicación fue más enfocada a avisar sobre el enlace roto. Así que la marcare como: ***Esta pregunta ya tiene una respuesta***.