# ¿Qué etiquetas HTML están permitidas en los sitios de Stack Exchange?

Tags: soporte, formato, diseño, propuesta-de-faq

El motor de Stack Overflow utiliza [Markdown](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) para preguntas y respuestas. De acuerdo con la especificación del Markdown, está permitido mezclar etiquetas **HTML** y **Markdown**.

Sin embargo, no *todas* las etiquetas HTML están permitidas, pues si no esto sería el paraíso del [XSS](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

¿Qué etiquetas HTML están permitidas y por tanto pueden usarse en los sitios de Stack Exchange?

<sub>Publicación basada en [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/209901) de Meta.SE.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Etiquetas HTML permitidas

El motor de Stack Exchange solo permite el siguiente **subconjunto seguro, incluido en la lista blanca de etiquetas HTML**:

```
<a>              - enlace.
<b>              - negrita, a utilizar en último extremo. Mejor usar <h1>-<h3>, <em> y <strong>
<blockquote>     - especifica una sección que está citada de otra fuente.
<code>           - define un trozo de código de programación.
<del>            - elimina, usado para mostrar modificaciones.
<dd>             - describe un elemento en una lista de descripción <dl>.
<dl>             - lista de descripción.
<dt>             - título de un elemento en una lista de descripción <dl>.
<em>             - énfasis.
<h1>, <h2>, <h3> - títulos.
<i>              - cursiva.
<img>            - especifica una etiqueta para una imagen.
<kbd>            - representa introducción de datos por parte de un usuario (normalment teclado).
<li>             - elemento de lista en una lista ordenada <ol> o desordenada <ul>.
<ol>             - lista ordenada.
<p>              - párrafo.
<pre>            - elemento pre mostrado en un tamaño fijo y sin modificar los saltos de línea.
<s>              - tachado.
<sup>            - superíndice: el texto aparece medio carácter por encima de la línea base.
                   usado para notas al pie u otros formatos.
<sub>            - subíndice: aparece medio carácter por debajo de la línea base.
<strong>         - define texto importante.
<strike>         - tachado, que está deprecado. Úsese <del> en lugar de esto.
<ul>             - lista no ordenada.
<br>             - salto de línea.
<hr>             - define un cambio de tema en el contenido, normalmente mediante una línea horizontal.
```

Ten en cuenta que dado que permitimos las etiquetas HTML anteriores, **para que estas etiquetas se vean como texto, debes escapar el carácter `<`**. Puedes escapar '<' marcándolo como código (con sangría o comillas invertidas como se hace a continuación) o utilizando la entidad HTML `&lt;`.

### Atributos permitidos

#### Atributos de "img"

Los siguientes atributos están permitidos en la etiqueta `<img>`, pero ten en cuenta que el tema móvil impone un `width` máximo de 90%, por lo que la especificación de una `height` podría no escalar la imagen proporcionalmente en los sitios móviles.

**¡El orden de los atributos es importante!** ¡Usar un orden diferente (por ejemplo, `width` antes de `height`) eliminará la etiqueta!

```
src=""
width="" (hasta 999; no incluyas la extensión 'px')
height="" (hasta 999; no incluyas la extensión 'px'; véase la nota de arriba)
alt=""
title=""
```

#### Atributos de `a`

Los siguientes atributos están permitidos en la etiqueta `<a>`:

```
href=""
title=""
```

### Notas importantes

- Las etiquetas HTML no listadas anteriormente se eliminan de la salida. Se pueden mostrar en la vista previa del cliente, pero siempre se eliminarán en el servidor.
- **Debes añadir las etiquetas *exactamente como se muestra*. Cualquier desviación de esta lista (agregar espacios adicionales, usar comillas simples o sin comillas, etc.) significa que la etiqueta se eliminará.**
- No permitimos (ni permitiremos) las etiquetas `<table>`. Lo siento. Esto es intencional y por diseño. Si necesitas una "tabla" rápida y sucia, usa `<pre>` y el diseño ASCII.